# How to Maintain Migration folder for test server and production server in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration, release-management

I have been dealing with this issue for a long time now. Our company has two django servers one for testing purpose and the other for deployment purpose, each with their own databases and migrations.

My initial solution was to simply maintain two migration folders:

```
-->migrations
-->migrations(P)
```

As seen above *migrations(P)* denotes the production level *migrations*, this config is used mainly during the testing phase where all the migrations are related to test database and some times it is swapped to the following folder structure when we are in production mode migrations:

```
-->migrations
-->migrations(T)
```

In the above case *migrations(T)* are related to test database and *migrations* are related to production level server.

This worked well but sometimes when there are multiple commits from other developers and also i work on it myself, due to the folder swapping the migration files get merged and messed up causing in a crash.

Sorry if my question is a little confusing.
Any alternative suggestion or approaches for maintaining production and test level database migrations would be helpful

Comment: Why do the test database and the production database need different schemas? I'd assume they would have the same structure.

Comment: Well, I think it's better to create a separate branch for test and put the migration folder in gitignore, so while migrating the code to production, it won't update the migration folder of the production.

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one migrations directory for an app. Your release management process needs to be more robust to prevent overwriting migrations. This could be caught in code reviews before code gets merged into master or some other stable-type branch. A reviewer should notice a migration being deleted and raise the issue.

Now regarding how do you manage a test database with multiple developers staging different and potentially conflicting migrations. You need communication as a team and attention to detail. For 95% of cases, the migrations need to be reverse-able. If a migration isn't, that developer needs to communicate that to the other developers that it's going out on staging and is going to control it until A) it's deployed or B) the test database is forked from production or restored from a backup before the migration.

The other part of communication is determining who is taking the test environment and determining if there's applied migrations that aren't in your branch. Before your branch gets deployed, you need to reverse those other migrations. Then you're safe to deploy your code and run your migrations. This is why reversible migrations are extremely important.

A difficult part is when migrations do get merged to master, any development that has migrations that depend on the newly merged migrations applications need to be merged via [`makemigrations --merge`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations-merge) or they can renamed to the count and have their dependencies corrected.

If these things are hard for your organization to do via unwritten rules, then it sounds like you need to implement some more rigid process around your releases. Getting your database out of sync with migrations can be a difficult problem to solve. It's made especially worse when it's on a production database and causes customer facing problems. Your organization needs to manage its risk effectively via release management.